# Twitter API with c#

Tags: c#, twitter

How to view mentions on twitter, the twitter post that mention us in their post by using c# and integrate with twitter API. already got to view all my self post using API. then use the same way to display mentions of me. but it is return this error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

And this is my code which is it is worked for view all of our own post:

```
protected void getMentionV3(string resource_url, string q)
    {
        resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?"
        q = twitterUserName

        var oauth_token = _accessToken;
        var oauth_token_secret = _accessTokenSecret; 
        var oauth_consumer_key = _consumerKey;
        var oauth_consumer_secret = _consumerSecret;

        var oauth_version = "1.0";
        var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

        var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
            - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                        "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}";

        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                    oauth_consumer_key,
                                    oauth_nonce,
                                    oauth_signature_method,
                                    oauth_timestamp,
                                    oauth_token,
                                    oauth_version,
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(q)
                                    );

        baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

        string oauth_signature;
        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        // create the request header
        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                        );



        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string html = "";
        try
        {
            JArray jsonDat = JArray.Parse(objText);
            for (int x = 0; x < jsonDat.Count(); x++)
            {

                html += jsonDat[x]["id"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                html += jsonDat[x]["text"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                html += jsonDat[x]["created_at"].ToString() + "<br/><hr/>";


            }
            mydiv.InnerHtml = html;
        }
        catch (Exception twit_error)
        {
            mydiv.InnerHtml = html + twit_error.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not referencing the correct URL.

You have

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?
```

...and the [Twitter API Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/mentions) say you should use...

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions.json?
```

Comment: thank you for your respons.i already tried both URL but still have the same problem

Comment: Are you sure that the keys are still valid?  You are able to retrieve a user timeline using the same keys?  If that is the case, then I would compare that method to this one line-by-line to see if this code contains an error in the OAUth section.